# Data-Target of Modal don't want to work with numbers

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my html code, I can't give numbers to data-target.

But it work with character (Read PS for information)

Exemple :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#12"><i class="fas fa-info"></i></button>
```

Don't open :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="12" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

PS : I can't use anything exept number because they are use in database for id detection.

PS 2 : If it's not possible, just they it and I gonna delete my post :)

Comment: Class and ID names can't start with a number (they're supposed to be able to in HTML5) but in reality, it rarely works.

Comment: So if they can't start by number, can they have something like 'abc1' ?

Comment: Yep `m123` or `modal123` are both perfectly fine. I'm not sure what the rationale was for that but it's in the HTML 4 spec that they must start with a letter and most browsers still seem to want it that way.

Comment: Perfect thank you that's work :)